(C) Is there anything wrong?
I am making video transfer code with UDP socket (using C)
Transfer was successful, so I try to add checksum error detection.
This part of code have a problem
 while (1) // loop for ever
    {
        char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
        size_t bytesread = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, file);

        // bytesread contains the number of bytes actually read
        if (bytesread == 0)
        {
            printf("sending video file completed\n");
            char fileFinMessage[] = "fin";

            if (sendto(clients[id].socket, fileFinMessage, sizeof(fileFinMessage), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&clients[id].address, sizeof(clients[id].address)) < 0)
            {
                perror("sendto() failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("sent fin message completed\n");
           
            // my problem the code is stopping at "sent fin message completed" 
            printf("hello world"); //it dosen't print hello world 
            unsigned short checksum = calculateChecksum(file);
            sprintf(buffer, "%d", checksum);
            printf("buffer is %s", buffer);
            sendto(clients[id].socket, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&clients[id].address, sizeof(clients[id].address));
            fclose(file);
   
            break;
           
        }
        // send the data
        sendto(clients[id].socket, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&clients[id].address, sizeof(clients[id].address));
    } 

when I run this code
the code stoping like this it doesn't print "hello world", and I think it does not break infinite loop.
This is my entire Server code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PORT 8888
#define BUF_SIZE 1254
#define MAX_CLIENTS 10
#define MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE 1024

typedef struct
{
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int socket;
    int id;
} Client;

Client clients[MAX_CLIENTS];
pthread_t threads[MAX_CLIENTS];
int clientCount = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

// calculate checksum
unsigned short calculateChecksum(FILE *file)
{
    unsigned short checksum = 0;
    int ch;

    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        checksum += (unsigned char)ch;
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    return checksum;
}

//function for multiThread
void *handleClient(void *arg)
{
    int id = *((int *)arg);
    char buffer[MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE];
    ssize_t bytesRead;

    // video file
    FILE *file;
    char *filename = "video.mp4";
    // open video file
    file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        perror("File opening failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    ssize_t bytes_read;
    // sending viedo file
    size_t fsize;
    
    //problem code...
    while (1)
    {
        char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
        size_t bytesread = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, file);

        // bytesread contains the number of bytes actually read
        if (bytesread == 0)
        {
            printf("sending video file completed\n");
            char fileFinMessage[] = "fin";

            if (sendto(clients[id].socket, fileFinMessage, sizeof(fileFinMessage), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&clients[id].address, sizeof(clients[id].address)) < 0)
            {
                perror("sendto() failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("sent fin message completed\n");
            // sending checksum
            
            //my problem
            printf("hello world"); //this is debuging code but it dosen't working
            //code for calculate and send checksum to client
            unsigned short checksum = calculateChecksum(file);
            sprintf(buffer, "%d", checksum);
            printf("buffer is %s", buffer);
            sendto(clients[id].socket, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&clients[id].address, sizeof(clients[id].address));
            fclose(file);
   
            break;
           
        }
        // send the data
        sendto(clients[id].socket, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&clients[id].address, sizeof(clients[id].address));
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int serv_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_adr;
    char message[BUF_SIZE];
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    socklen_t clnt_adr_sz = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    ssize_t str_len;

    // Create socket
    if ((serv_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // socket address
    memset(&serv_adr, 0, sizeof(serv_adr));
    serv_adr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_adr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_adr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // binding socket
    if (bind(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_adr, sizeof(serv_adr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("bind() error");
        exit(1);
    }

    // mutex Init
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

    printf("waiting for client...\n");

    // Create a thraed for each client
    while (1)
    {
        // receive message from client
        str_len = recvfrom(serv_sock, message, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&clients[clientCount].address, &clnt_adr_sz);
        if (str_len < 0)
        {
            perror("recvfrom error");
            exit(1);
        }

        // print message
        message[str_len] = '\0';
        printf("client %d say: %s\n", clientCount + 1, message);

        // Add client to the list
        clients[clientCount].socket = serv_sock;
        clients[clientCount].id = clientCount;
        // create thread for client
        pthread_create(&threads[clientCount], NULL, handleClient, (void *)&clients[clientCount].id);
        clientCount++;
        // send a message to the client
        sprintf(message, "hello i am server, you are Client %d\n", clientCount);
        if (sendto(clients[clientCount - 1].socket, message, strlen(message), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&clients[clientCount - 1].address, sizeof(clients[clientCount - 1].address)) < 0)
        {
            perror("sendto error");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    close(serv_sock);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    return 0;
}

This is my Client code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1254
#define PORT 8888

unsigned short calculateChecksum(FILE *file)
{
    unsigned short checksum = 0;
    int ch;

    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        checksum += (unsigned char)ch; 
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    return checksum;
}

int main(){
    int sock;
    char message[BUFSIZE];
    int str_len;
    socklen_t adr_sz;

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, client_addr;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sock == -1){
        printf("socket() error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    char hello_message[] = "hello i am client";
    sendto(sock, hello_message, strlen(hello_message), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    adr_sz = sizeof(client_addr);
    str_len=recvfrom(sock,message,BUFSIZE,0,(struct sockaddr*)&client_addr,&adr_sz);
 
   
    message[str_len] = '\0';
    printf("Server say: %s\n", message);

    FILE *file = fopen("received_test.mp4", "wb");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("File opening failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int nbyte = BUFSIZE;
    while(1){
        nbyte = recvfrom(sock, message, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, &adr_sz);
        if(!strcmp(message, "fin")){
            printf("File received success \n");
            break;
        }
        fwrite(message, BUFSIZE, 1, file);
    }

    recvfrom(sock, message, BUFSIZE,0,(struct sockaddr*)&client_addr,&adr_sz);
    printf("checksum = %s\n",message);
    unsigned short checksum = calculateChecksum(file);
    char checksumCheck[BUFSIZE];
    sprintf(checksumCheck, "%d", checksum);
    if(!strcmp(message,checksumCheck)){
        printf("checksum correct");
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(file);
    close(sock);
    
    return 0;
}

If I run server.c output is below
❯ ./TestServer
waiting for client...
client 1 say: hello i am client
sending video file completed
sent fin message completed

problem:
it dosen't print "hello world" ( It dosen't run below "sent fin message completed")

Add a \n to your printf statements so they will likely flush the buffer. It would be simple to run your code in a debugger, place a breakpoint on that line, and see if it was being hit and what happens next.

It works! Thanks.
But I don't know why...
Is '\n' is just change line? how it works?

For line buffered output, like a terminal, the \n will flush the output buffer. Without it the data can be buffered for a while until the buffer fills up. You can also use fflush(stdout); if you really want to force it.
